How to add Text Variable value to the downloaded CSV file name
We have a panel by name "Block Load Profile". User needs to input a value in a text variable and the related data is filtered on the report. Today when user downloads this data using Panel menu > Inspect > Data > Download CSV, the CSV file has date appended to the panel name like "Block Load Profile-data-2024-08-02 11_47_08".
We would like to add the value of Text Variable (passed by user as a filter) in the file name so for above example the filename will be "Block Load Profile-data-AL0100002-2024-08-02 11_47_08" where 'AL0100002' is the value passed entered by use in the text variable.
I tried to edit panel name and appended the variable name in the panel name e.g. Block Load Profile-data_{$DeviceNumber}. I was expecting that this will include the value of the variable in the downloaded file name. But downloaded file name had the variable name and not variable value passed by user.

May be you just have a typo? It should be Block Load Profile ${DeviceNumber}, not Block Load Profile {$DeviceNumber}

@ebabeshko, thanks for pointing out. It was a typo indeed.

I would appreciate, if someone could please provide inputs for this problem.
